# D-modules as ind-coherent sheaves over positive characteristics?

Tags: reference-request, d-modules, derived-algebraic-geometry, crystalline-cohomology

There is an interpretation of D-modules over "sufficiently nice" prestacks $X$ (read: various finiteness conditions apply, perhaps even smoothness) by Gaitsgory and Rozenbylum (see chapter I.4 [here](https://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Egaitsgde/GL/Vol2.pdf) and [this paper](https://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Egaitsgde/GL/Crystalstext.pdf)), in which one views D-modules as ind-coherent sheaves (i.e. filtered colimits of coherent sheaves) over so-called de Rham spaces $X_{dR}$ attached to the previously mentioned "nice" prestacks $X$. As I understand it, this is essentially using the fact that each crystal in quasi-coherent sheaves comes canonically equipped with a flat connection, and thus can be seen as a D-module; the approach by Gaitsgory-Rozenblyum is therefore a version of infinitesimal cohomology (in the sense of Grothendieck-Ogus) wherein establishing the six functors is somewhat easier, as now the six functors for D-modules can be deduced from the general theory of ind-coherent sheaves. There is, however, a caveat: our prestack $X$ has to be an object in characteristic $0$, and preferably over a field of characteristic $0$, as smooth schemes over fields are automatically reduced.

Now I am aware of the fact that there is also a theory of "arithmetic" D-modules, developed by Berthelot, wherein one replaces infinitesimal sites and all the businesses involving de Rham spaces with crystalline sites, whose objects are pd-immersions and whose coverage is the usual Zariski coverage. Given the somewhat *ad hoc* definition of pd-structures, **is it also possible (at least in principle) to reformulate the theory of arithmetic D-modules in the style of Gaitsgory and Rozenblyum** ? Have there been any attempts at this, and if this is not possible, why so ?

Comment: For a smooth scheme $X$, ind-coherent sheaves are a much less significant ingredient than the stack $X_{dR}$, from section 7 of Simpson's arXiv:alg-geom/9604005v1. If you try to mimic Simpson's construction to get crystalline cohomology, you need to take the DP envelope of the diagonal ideal, and for that to represent a functor, you would have to work on a category of rings with DP structures on their radicals.

Comment: Arithmetic D-modules are different from crystals on the crystalline site, if I understand correctly, and the later does not have six functor formalism.

Comment: @JonPridham One could simply work with the category of (animated) rings. The de Rham stack (outside characteristic 0) of $X$ is given by $R\mapsto X(\mathbb G_a^{\operatorname{dR}}(R))$, where $\mathbb G_a^{\operatorname{dR}}:=\operatorname{cofib}(\mathbb G_a^\sharp\to\mathbb G_a)$ and $\mathbb G_a^\sharp=\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb Z[T,T^2/2!,T^3/3!,\dots])$. See Bhatt's talk https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v2Jfk-NTjp4

Comment: @Z.M You can get that sort of construction just by putting divided powers into the de Rham stack, though for consistency with characteristic $0$ I'd expect a nilpotence condition on the elements $T^n/n!$ as well (so some sort of pro-object like a power series). Then $\mathbb{G}_a^{\sharp}$ is essentially just parametrising DP structures on the radical.

Comment: To clarify, if the OP's sole objection to DP structures is their non-uniqueness, then yes, simplicial rings provide a solution by allowing derived quotients, so it doesn't matter that the map  $\{\gamma \in I^{\mathbb{N}} ~:~ \binom{m+n}{n}\gamma_{m+n}=\gamma_m\gamma_n\}\to I$ sending $\gamma$ to $\gamma_1$ isn't injective, but I wouldn't regard that as avoiding divided powers.

Comment: @JonPridham If I understand correctly, in char $p$ and mixed char, one usually does not Hodge-complete, which should be closely related to the nilpotency that you want to impose. On the other hand, this approach has advantage that the prismatic analogue is directly related. In particular, without that, I don't know how to work out a category of "rings with $q$-PD structure" for the stacky approach.

Comment: @Z.M In mixed characteristic (so working over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ rather than $\mathbb{Z}$), the divided powers are giving you nilpotence for free, as $n! \to 0$. For $q$-analogues, structure has to go on the whole ring, not just the ideal. You get these sorts of constructions in http://arxiv.org/abs/1608.07142, in particular Prop 1.15 - if you clear out powers of $(q-1)$ from the denominators in mixed characteristic, it turns out that you get the functor $X^{q,p}$ from Remark 3.15 (via Prop 4.9 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.10530), whose cohomology is essentially $q$-crystalline.

Comment: @JonPridham My understanding is that, in Prop 1.15, your variables are of rank 1, and this does not seem to allow us to describe something like "the radical is stable under $q$-divided powers" (if you want to define a $q$-de Rham stack on the site of $\delta$-rings over $\mathbb Z_p[[q-1]]$).

Comment: @JonPridham Thanks for the clarifications. I wonder where do you prove that this $X^{q,p}$ is related to the "plethory" given by the subalgebra in Prop 1.15? In view of Bhatt–Lurie (and Drinfeld), given $X^{q,p}$, the functor defined on $\mathbb Z_p[[q-1]]$-algebras should be simply composing the cofree functor, i.e. taking Witt vectors. So which statement in your paper is essentially saying that $\operatorname{cofib}((\Psi^p)^{-1}([p]_qW(R))\to W(R))$, at least up to fpqc sheafification w.r.t. $R$, coincides with the one given in Prop 1.15?

Comment: @Z.M They don't coincide, because Prop 1.15 has extra powers of $(q-1)$ in the  denominator. REmoving them needs the Anschuetz-Le Bras paper, which roughly shows that the $\mathbb{Z}_p[x][[q-1]]$-subalgebra generated by the elements $(q-1)^k\lambda^k(\frac{y-x}{q-1})$ is just the $\lambda$-ring generated by $\frac{y^p-x^p}{[p]_q}$. However, Th 2.8 proves an analogue for $X^{q,p}_{strat}$ and Th 3.11 uses the local equivalence $X^{q,p}_{strat} \simeq X^{q,p}$ on perfectoid input to establish a version with $p$-power roots of $q$.

Comment: @Z.M I've just deleted my comments on plethories which I added too hastily; none of the rings in the resolution of $q$-de Rham is a plethory, as they aren't closed under the coadditivity map $x \mapsto x\otimes 1 +1\otimes x$. However, the functors there are all defined on $\lambda$- and $\delta$-rings, so (after modifying with powers of $(q-1)$) your last comment roughly holds if you remove $W$.

Comment: @JonPridham Thanks. For the appearance of $W$, it is used to define gadgets on ordinary rings instead of $\delta$-rings, and this works for prismatic cohomology after fpqc sheafification (Bhatt–Lurie should cover this).

Comment: @Z.M I'm well aware of what $W$'s doing - it features heavily in section 3 of my paper (and the big Witt vectors earlier). My point was just that Prop 1.15 is set up to define a functor on $\lambda$- or $\delta$-rings, not ordinary rings, so $W$ isn't needed to make a comparison. (If you do, it sends a flat $\mathbb{Z}[q]$-algebra $A$ to the image of the Teichmueller map $[A]\to W(A)/(q-1)$; you have to modify by powers of $(q-1)$ to get the functor sending $A$ to the image of $[A] \to W_p(A)/(\Psi^p){-1}[p]_q$, and that map's locally surjective. )

Comment: @Z.M One hopefully final comment. For a $q$-analogue of $\hat{\mathbb{G}}_a$, you work on $\lambda$-rings, starting from free (not cofree) $\lambda$-rings over $\mathbb{Z}[q]$ rather than polynomial rings. As in the second part of Remark 1.4, $\nu^k(a):= [k]_q!(q-1)^k\lambda^k(\frac{a}{q-1})$ gives a $q$-analogue of $a^k$, the recursive formula $\nu^k(a)=\sum_{i>0}(q-1)^{i-1} \lambda^i(a)\frac{[k-1]_q!}{[k-i]_q!}\nu^{k-i}(a) $ showing it has no denominators. Instead of $T^n/n!$, you then want to include $\nu^n(T)/[n]_q!$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following link to a set of notes seems to contain I was looking for. It's about so-called *crystalline spaces* associated to proper and separated smooth schemes (which are very similar to de Rham spaces of smooth schemes) and how arithmetic D-modules can be realised as quasi-coherent sheaves on these spaces, much like how D-modules in characteristic $0$ can be thought of as quasi-coherent sheaves on de Rham spaces (I'm brushing a lot of technicalities under the rug here).

In particular, propositions 7.3 and 7.5 seem to be the result that I was looking for.

[R. Gregoric, "Crystalline spaces"](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/gregoric/CrystalMath.pdf)